# Apache Solr - How to prevent splitting when searching phrases

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have the following fieldtype:

```
<fieldType name="textfield" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100"> 
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="3" max="30"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="3" max="30"/>
    <!--<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>-->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The problem I have is that when searching for a phrase using quotes, the results are the same as if there were no quotes, so if I search for let's say:
abc. 8
that'll show the same results of
"abc. 8"
And could the period split the text too?

In other words I just want to search for phrases when the query text is quoted.
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You've incorporated a `LengthFilterFactory` into your analyzer with minimum length 3.  The token `8` has length 1, and so will be eliminated both from the index and the query by that filter.  You're query syntax is correct, and if both terms were being indexed, a phrase query would be performed as you've specified.

Comment: is there a way to avoid a phrase being tokenized in the query? I mean, when searching for "abc. 8" I want to see it as a single token of 5 chars, so the 8 doesn't get eliminated from the query.

Comment: That would make it very difficult to search, since the tokenization in the index would still be tokenized.  You might create a query with a single token `abc. 8`, but your index would still only have the token `abc.`.  If you wish to be able to find the token `8`, I would guess that minimum length is simply not doing you any favors.

Comment: If you really need to support different tokenization schemes, the best solution would be to index two different versions of the text in differently named fields.